# JavaFX hover property

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GridPane which is populated by rectangles. What I want to do is to display a new pane while hovering over a particular rectangle(member of the grid pane). Lets have an example with this VBox code example below. How could I make it display on hover ?

```
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(RECTANGLE_SIZE, RECTANGLE_SIZE);
            r.hoverProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
                r.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                VBox box = new VBox();
                Button x = new Button("Test");
                box.getChildren().add(x);
            });
```

the set fill works properly

Answer (score 1):

In your example you need to specify `Node` which would be parent of `VBox`. For now you are always creating new `VBox`, but never add it to current scene graph. Try this:

```
r.hoverProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean show) -> {
      if (show) {
           VBox box = new VBox();
           Button x = new Button("Test");
           box.getChildren().add(x);
           parent.getChildren().add(box);
      } else {
           parent.getChildren().clear();
      }
});
```

Comment: What would be the parent node ? If I add it to the GridPane scene it clears all the rectangle objects

Comment: I would try to add your `GridPane` to `StackPane`, then add another empty `Pane` to StackPane. In this case you get layer above `GridPane` in which you can add `VBox`.